# Django - Mandar id a otra template?

Tags: django

[image: Detalle Del Torneo y sus equipos creados]

Template Detalle de torneo con sus equipos , al agregar equipo envia al template crear equipo , como enviar ese id del torneo y relacionar al equipo directamente , sin necesidad de un select.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## models.py

```
class Equipo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    color = RGBColorField()
    torneo = models.ForeignKey(Torneo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.nombre)
```

## views.py

```
class Equipo_CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Equipo
    template_name = "torneos/equipo_crear.html"
    form_class = Equipo_Form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('torneos:equipo_crear')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        torneo = Torneo.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])

    def form_valid(self, form_class):
        form_class.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id
        return super(Equipo_CreateView, self).form_valid(form_class)
```

## urls.py

```
    url(r'^detalle/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(Torneo_DetailView.as_view()), name='torneo_detalle'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/equipo/$', login_required(Equipo_CreateView.as_view()), name='equipo_crear'),
```

## torneo_detalle.html

```
    <a href="{% url 'torneos:equipo_crear' object.id%}">Agregar Equipo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar datos de la template a la view tienes varias opciones.

Via URL

```
/detalle_torneo/5
```

Que se gestionaría via url y en la template hay que recogerlo como paramentro:

```
url(r'^detalle_torneo/(?P<torneo_id>\d+)/$', 'nombreview', name='nombreurl')
def nombreview(request, torneo_id):
    torneo = Torneo.objects.get(id=torneo_id)
    #El resto de cosas pasandole a la view el torneo directamene
```

Si fuera una Class based view:

```
class nombreview(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        torneo = Torneo.objects.get(id=kwargs['torneo_id'])
```

Mandar un parametro GET

un parametro GET lo generarías añadiendo después de la url del enlace el nombre de la variable + el valor

```
<a href="{% url 'tuvista' %}?nombrevar=valor&otronombre={{ template_var}}>link</a>
```

Que quedaria:

```
/detalle_torneo?id_torneo=1

url(r'^detalle_torneo/$', 'detalletor', name='url')
def detalletor(request):
    torneo = request.GET['id_torneo']
```

Mandar un parámetro POST (igual que el get pero no se ve en url y no tiene máximo de caracteres)

```
def assign_tecnic_eaes(request):
    if request.POST:
    torneo = request.POST.get('id_torneo')
```

Comment: Bro, desde donde dices sobre el parametro GET , no entiendo la parte de la url en adelante, ya añadi el codigo en la pregunta por si es de ayuda.